# Store active list selection after reloading the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, list, listitem

I need to make sure the list item is selected even after the page gets refreshed. Here's the code:

```
 <style>
    li a.selected 
      {
        color: red;
      } 
  </style>


   <ul>
      <li><a href="arasu.php?something_dynamically">test</a></li>
      <li><a href="arasu.php?something_dynamically">test 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="arasu.php?something_dynamically">test 2</a></li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Uh... what? You mean apply the class `selected` after page refresh? Well, what have you tried?

Comment: Use an if statement in php to add the class to the right link tag. This is assuming the above is in a php file or template.

Comment: actually i am new  don't know how to solve this..

Comment: @PattatharasuN clicking on the link will redirect you to the specified url (i.e. arasu.php?something_dynamically) in your case. I think all you want is to mark the clicked/visisted list item with red color after page reload or when the user will be back to this page. am i right?

Comment: @Mambro yes, you are right, what is the correct solution?

Comment: @PattatharasuN that's good. I've given an answer below. Read it and mark it as answer or give it an upvote if it helps otherwise feel free to ask again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you might want to try something like that :

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="arasu.php?item=1" <?php if($_GET['item'] == 1):?>class="active"<?php endif;?>>test</a></li>
  <li><a href="arasu.php?item=2" <?php if($_GET['item'] == 2):?>class="active"<?php endif;?>>test 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="arasu.php?item=3" <?php if($_GET['item'] == 3):?>class="active"<?php endif;?>>test 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to distinct the visited anchor tag `<a>` then you need `:visited` selector in CSS. Rather than giving it a class in your css, you can use the CSS default `:visited`  selector as below:

```
li a:visited
{
    color: red;
}
```